# Passing values to a form from a common drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a drop-down menu which will be used multiple times within the webpage.
Now I want to use it in a form.

How can I to pass the values from the drop-down menu?

Common drop-down menu:

```
<script id="dm" type="text/template">
    <select name="dd">
       <option value="">Select Quty</option>
       <option value="less ">50 - 60</option>
       <option value="xl ">Above 80</option>
    </select>
</script>
```

Appending in to `#InputsWrapper`:

```
$('#InputsWrapper').append(inWrap).append(
    $($('#dm').html()).attr('dd', newdm)
);
```

Getting out the values on changed:

```
$(document).on('change', 'newdm', function(e) {
   $('#nameWrap').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `$('#dm').html()` returns `String`, so setting attribute `dd` is not valid here. Also I don't see where `inWrap` is defined and what for it is used.

Comment: @Regent: The extra $() converts the string to a DOM element first before adding the attribute

Comment: there is no class `.dd` in your code, but you bind an event listener on it. Did you mean `$($('#dm').html()).addClass('dd')` instead of `$($('#dm').html()).attr('dd', newdm)`?

Comment: @JanHommes: `.attr('dd', newdm)` is correct to my understanding. But like you guessed I think the issue is within `$('#InputsWrapper').append(inWrap).append($($('#dm').html()).attr('dd', newdm)
);`

Comment: You changed your code. Now your event listener is searching for a html element named `<newdm>` and you are setting the attribute `dd` to  the variable `newdm`. This variable is not visible in this part. Try to make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to clarify your needs. Mostly this simplifies your app and you find the answer yourself.

Comment: @Nelie `on('change', 'newdm'` is also incorrect - `newdm` will be treated as HTML tag, not as element attribute. You should probably add specific class for newly created element, and use this class in `change` event handler.

Comment: @JanHommes: See this Fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6q9hn5Ln/6/` WHen "Add a Thought" is clicked 2 text fields are added. Now how would you pass the drop down value to either of the textfields?

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9hn5Ln/9/)? Update:[http://jsfiddle.net/6q9hn5Ln/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9hn5Ln/10/)

Comment: @JanHommes: yes that's very close to what I was looking for. Thanks.